# LINQ join method chain syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, method-chaining

I have two lists:

`Queries(0)` and `Queries(1)`, which are a `IEnumerable(Of Object())`.

Now, I would like to join (inner join) the two lists like so:

```
Dim ResultQuery As IEnumerable(Of Object()) = Nothing
ResultQuery = Queries(0).Join(
                          Queries(1), 
                          Function(Table1) Table1(0), 
                          Function(Table2) Table2(0), 
                          Function(Table1, Table2) Table1)
```

But the `ResultQuery` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are `Table1(0)` and `Table2(0)` ever equal? Because that's what you're trying to join the queries on.

Comment: Yes, they are always equal. Table1(0) is a string value and Table2(0) is the same string value. But of course, they can be different too. But now, both values are always equal.

Comment: do you get results if you write the same query using the linq query syntax method?

Comment: Add some sample data which you are using if possible.

Comment: It was my fault, Queries(1) didn't contain the corresponding field. I corrected it, but now I get an OutOfMemory exception. Each of Queries(0) and Queries(1) contains 30.000 rows.

Comment: If I lower the number of rows, it works. I need to search on this topic.

Comment: I know now: because the joined field values are always the same, it would produce 30k*30k rows.